# Comparing results of two different scanning methodologies, often with small numbers

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm involved in a study where we are looking at patients in a hospital who had both a CT scan and a panorex x-ray.  There were 100 total patients who had both and we had a dr look through the results independently and "diagnose" the scan.  Also, I'm sorry the design of this study is not great for stats, it wasn't well thought out.

So the Dr. would look at a ct of patient John Smith and record all the bone fractures he saw and all the dental damage to teeth he saw.  He would do that for a bunch of other patients and then randomly he would get back to John Smith except this time it was diagnosing his x-ray, where he would record the same type of information (fractures and dental damage).

When all the scans were diagnosed we had a panel of judges look at the scans where he didn't find the same thing (lets say John Smith's ct had 2 fractures but xray had 3) and the panel would decide which scan was "correct".  I.e. for this example the panel would decide it really was 3 and ct just didn't show it.

This is all with the intent to show which scanning methodology was often "better".

My first set of questions are:  the researchers involved would like me to tell them what method was statistically better for a few of these examples and I'm at a loss:

- There were 26 ct scans (of 100 total ct scans) where the CT was superior at showing fractures than the xray for their respective patient.  2 xrays were better than their respective ct for their patient for fractures.  Is there a way to statistically show ct was better for fracture identification?
- The same kinda thing but for dental damage.  Often smaller numbers too.  Lets say 9 scans had different dental damage findings and 6 of those times the xray was better, 3 times the ct was. Is there a way to statistically say that xray was better?

And as a follow-up that I THINK I know the answer to, but would love a simple yes/no confirmation:
After the data was all collected, a separate Dr. looked at the cases where CT and Xray were different and made the judgement of whether if he had only had one of the scans, would he have treated the patient differently.  I.e. "the xray only shows one fracture, the ct had shown 4, so if I only had the xray I wouldn't have treated all of the patients fractures and his medical treatment would be different".  The researchers I'm involved with have asked me to show that ct was different from xray for these things statistically, the problem is that this is often very small numbers.  I.e. 26 scans were different at all in terms of what medical treatment would happen, 3 were different with regard to dental damage, and 2 of those 3 were superior on the ct.  So the researchers are asking me to compare the ct vs xray for that tiny category of 2 vs 1.  That's impossible correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very small counts, it is traditional to use Fisher's Exact test.

If I am reading your narrative correctly, the contingency table
with counts for CT correct/incorrect on the first row and
counts for x-ray correct/incorrect on the second row is as follows:

```
TBL1 = rbind(c(26,74), c(2,98)); TBL1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   26   74
[2,]    2   98
```

Fisher's Exact test shows a highly significant
difference between the two methods, with P-value about $0$
(very much smaller than 5%).

```
fisher.test(TBL1)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL1
p-value = 6.04e-07
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   4.048854 152.457128
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  17.02357
```

The corresponding chi-squared test (without Yates correction) gives
a similarly highly significant result.

```
chisq.test(TBL1, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL1
X-squared = 23.92, df = 1, p-value = 1.004e-06
```

For the second situation you mentioned, it seems the contingency
table is:

```
TBL2 = rbind(c(6,3), c(3,6));  TBL2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    3
[2,]    3    6
```

Fisher's Exact test finds no significant difference here:

```
fisher.test(TBL2)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL2
p-value = 0.3469
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.405943 43.344206
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  3.679564
```

A straightforward chi-squared test gives a questionable P-value
on account of the small counts. However, R can simulate a more
accurate P-value, in substantial agreement with Fisher's Exact test.

```
chisq.test(TBL2, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL2
X-squared = 2, df = NA, p-value = 0.3508
```

You are correct that counts in your final example are too small
for a meaningful statistical test.